# ListView having dynamic views for each row

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview

I want to display data in a `ListView` (For better performance and recycling) BUT each row of the `ListView` will have a vertical `LinearLayout` but is not guranteed that how many `TextViews` will be there in every LinearLayout.

Currently I am using the `ViewHolder` pattern and I am dynamically adding views to the `LinearLayout` in the `getView()` method of `ListView`. Note: I am calling `linearLayout.removeAllViews()` before adding views to it so as to eliminate duplicate views in `LinearLayout`.

**Prolem**
The performance is very slow due to adding removing and adding dynamic views in `ListView`.

Any other idea how I can handle this situation?
Shall I prefer a `ScrollView` and a vertical `LinearLayout` instead of `ListView`?

Please Help.

Let me know if any further clarification is required from my side.

Comment: Consider hiding and showing `TextView`s dynamically in `getView()`, if you have to choose b/w some already known values.

Answer (score 2):

If you're experiencing slow performance, it might behoove you to get rid of as much processing in the `getView()` method as possible. `getView()` is called every time an item is created (new or recycled) and removing all views and redrawing them kind of defeats the purpose of recycling.

If you can parse through your data and simplify it before sending it to the adapter, that might take some load off the `getView()` method and help your performance issues.

EDIT: Like M-WaJeEh said above, controlling stuff with `Visibility.VISIBLE` and `Visibility.GONE` usually works better in my experience than changing the number of things that get inflated.

Comment: hmm I am parsing the JSON data and I am forming it as ArrayList and Beans. In getView() I am only iterating over data and generating view  that's it..
Do you want me to create views prior to creating list adapter??

Comment: Right. So you'll have the maximum possible number or `TextViews` all inflate (hopefully it's not a very large number), but set their default visibility to `android:visibility="gone"`. Then, in your `getView()` inflate all of them and determine which ones to show. If your maximum number of `TextView`s is huge, you might want to look into using an `ExpandableListView` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Changing the visibility of views in a ListView doesn't help. The ListView still lags when I am trying to scroll.. :(